# Scroll viewer resize (Right bottom corner ) in wpf

Tags: wpf, telerik, wpf-controls

I have scroll viewer enabled in treeview and listbox and have even customized the scroll bars refering [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37366/Styling-A-ScrollViewer-Scrollbar-In-WPF) site and i have acheived what i need .My scroll bar is now looking like below

[image]

but i need my scrollbar to be look like this

[image]

I need that space in right bottom corner to be filled with horizontal or vertical scroll bar .Is it possible in wpf ??

Below is the customized style for the scrollbar

```
<local:ThicknessConverter x:Key="ThicknessConverter" />
    <Style x:Key="{x:Type ScrollBar}" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="18" />
                <Setter Property="Template"

                    Value="{StaticResource HorizontalScrollBar}" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="18"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto" />
                <Setter Property="Template"

                    Value="{StaticResource VerticalScrollBar}" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Name" Value="PART_VerticalScrollBar">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ScrollViewer},Converter={StaticResource ThicknessConverter}}">
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>

        </Style.Triggers>


    </Style>
```

and here is there treeview code

```
   <telerik:RadTreeView x:Name="radTreeView"   Background="#4E4E4E" Margin="0,0,456,0" Grid.Row="2"  
              ItemsSource="{x:Static local:MainWindow.AnimalCategories}" ItemPrepared="treeView_ItemPrepared" 
                             ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <telerik:RadTreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Animals}">
                    <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Category}" />
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>

                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </telerik:RadTreeView.ItemTemplate>

        </telerik:RadTreeView>
```

Comment: How about providing your current code?

Answer (score 4):

Below is a way to do it:

***XAML:***

```
 <ScrollViewer Height="400" Width="400" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" >
    <ScrollViewer.Resources>
        <local:ThicknessConverter x:Key="ThicknessConverter" />
        <Style TargetType="ScrollBar">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ScrollViewer},Converter={StaticResource ThicknessConverter}}">
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ScrollViewer.Resources>
</ScrollViewer>
```

***Converter:***

```
public class ThicknessConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var scrollBars = FindVisualChildren<ScrollBar>(value as DependencyObject);
        foreach (var scrollBar in scrollBars)
        {
            if (scrollBar.Orientation == Orientation.Horizontal)
            {
              return  new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0 - scrollBar.ActualHeight);
            }
        }
        return new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (depObj != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
            {
                DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
                if (child != null && child is T)
                {
                    yield return (T)child;
                }

                foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
                {
                    yield return childOfChild;
                }
            }
        }
    }        

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

***OUTPUT:***

[image: Scroll]

Comment: @dahsra are you using some other style for your scrollviewer? If yes please give the code or move the trigger in my style into that style.

Comment: actually am not using seperate scroll viewer .I am just using treeview default scroll bar and for that scrollbar i have other style defined

Comment: @dahsra everything is alright here... In the treeview the style will also work... it's the HorizontalScrollBar & VerticalScrollBar that is creating the problem.... have you defined them yourself here? if yes please give the code.

Comment: @dahsra you can check this theory by commenting OverridesDefaultStyle setter with template setters, everything will work fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110245/discussion-between-dahsra-and-kylo-ren).

Comment: @dahsra I'm sorry can't help you this way any more... you need to provide the sample you are using then I'll be able to find out the actual problem. As per my investigation the telerik control use the same scrollbar of WPF so the above solution should work perfectly as you know it's working perfectly for normal TreeView.